# Changing the default styling of tables in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, visual-editor

I've deployed mediawiki in my organization with the visual editor. While you can add and edit tables easily in the visual editor, it does not yet allow you to change the styling.

I'd really like for tables in the visualeditor by default to be created with class="wikitable sortable" by default. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you want "wikitable sortable" to be added only to new tables created with VisualEditor, or also to old tables? See also the manual on how to [customise the interface](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface#Customizing_the_interface).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is currently impossible from within VisualEditor, see [Bug T95189: Support sortable columns in tables](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T95189).

You should be able to follow the manual on how to [customise the interface](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface#Customizing_the_interface) to apply `sortable` (or directly the tablesorter code) to every `wikitable` table.